# How do I style the console output to look pretty?

Tags: javascript, java, python, firebase, npm

How do programs like `npm` and `firebase` produce interesting and pretty console output, as their commands are being executed?

For example:

`$ firebase deploy`

or

`$ npm i <some-package>`

Comment: what do you mean by "interesting" and "pretty"?

Comment: @joelb I assume he means with the colored text, emojis and progress bars. Though for emojis you can just copy and paste it from the here: https://emojipedia.org/ 

Comment: https://github.com/tholman/console-dot-frog

Comment: https://github.com/chalk/chalk
https://github.com/sindresorhus/ora

Comment: @ShahriarShojib This is exactly what I meant. Chalk especially. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get a console output similar to the above mentioned packages and some other famous packages, there are multiple approaches that you can follow. And it all depends on the **programming language** you use as well.

Just to give some context into the answer; pretty console output could vary from various designs to different colours and moving loaders.

[image]

[image]

Since the question is on *how these programs build this kind of outputs*, I want to elaborate on this more. Given below are some approaches.

**Manually manipulating the Print Statement of your Programming Language**

This is the traditional approach, which can be used to do various designs on the Console, where you can use loops and proper spacing to print out various patterns on your console. This is highly traditional, but some users prefer this to keep it simple. Remember the star pattern problems we used to solve during basic algorithm competitions.. ;) You can put that knowledge to practice.

Also, this is very limited to only getting shapes out, and coloring and styling is nearly impossible without libraries.

**Use Libraries built specifically for this**

For `node`, a famous library would be [CHALK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk). For `Python`, you can use [colorful](https://github.com/timofurrer/colorful). Similarly, there are libraries available for other languages as well.